# Custom rendering using render-content property in element-ui transfer component not working

Tags: element-ui

I'm trying to add the **title** attribute to the default span tag, which is used in element-ui data item rendering for the transfer component.

From the documentation, I came across the render-content property of the element-ui component. This property gets assigned to a custom render function. As per the docs, this render function can be modified to change the way the data items get displayed. So here's the code for the Vue component wrapper for the Transfer component:

```
base-transfer(
  ref="transfer"
  filterable
  v-bind:data="participantsSport"
  v-bind:filter-placeholder="$t('event.details.search')"
  v-bind:props="{key: 'uuid', label: 'name'}"
  v-bind:render-content="renderParticipants"
  v-model="participantsSelected")
```

And here's my render function, which is a public function in the same class where the above template is being used:

```
public renderParticipants(h, option: {key: string; label: string}): string {
  return `
    <span title = ${option.label}>
      ${option.key} - ${option.label}
    </span>
  `;
}
```

**Expected output:** It should render the data items with the label value in the title attribute for each data item.

**Current output:** Only checkboxes without the label or the attribute are shown.

**Question 1:** Is this the correct way of adding the title for each data item in the transfer component of element-ui?

**Question 2:** In the official doc, it's mentioned:

> In a real project, render-content will work if relevant dependencies
>   are correctly configured.

What does it require me to do in addition to what I'm doing already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what worked for me was this:

```
  public renderParticipants(
    h: CreateElement,
    option: { name: string }): VNode {

    return h('span', { attrs: { title: option.name } }, option.name);
  }
```